# Token Authentication Logout: should I delete the token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, devise, access-token

I am building a token-authentication system for a mobile backend with Rails. I understand there is devise, but our auth path is kind like different so I build it from scratch.

Just curious, when a user log out. What should happen to the token in Mobile end and Server end.

1. Should the token in mobile end be deleted?
2. Should the token in server end be deleted? And a new will be generated when this user logged in again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the token is unique by user and it used to identify the user ,so you don't delete it after logout ,for mobile you may save it to cookies to enable something like remember me but on the server you don't need to delete it

Comment: Thanks Remon, so can you explain more on that? I am thinking on the mobile end, a token will be stored in the sqlite db, and upon logout, this token in mobile db should be deleted. Is this the right approach? Also, in the server end, you said I shouldn't delete the token when the user logout, right? Thanks!

Comment: when user signed in,server will send the auth_token to the mobile ,so every request sent to the server must have the auth_token ,so server can identify the user ,after log out you can remove the auth_token from the mobile end ,or you can implement something like remember me so auth_token are stored in a cookie ,so user don't need to sign in every time